# schema error while converting Vector collection to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a vector collection named `values` which I'm trying to convert to a dataframe

```
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[(String, Double)] = Vector((1,1.0), (2,2.4), (3,3.7), (4,5.0), (5,4.9))
```

I have defined a custom schema as follows and tried to do the conversion.

```
val customSchema = new StructType()
    .add("A", IntegerType, true)
    .add("B", DoubleType, true)

val df = values.toDF.schema(customSchema)
```

This gives me an error saying,

```
error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fieldIndex: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField <and>
  (names: Set[String])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (name: String)org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
```

I've tried all the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912804/overloaded-method-value-apply-with-alternatives?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635606/overloaded-method-error-using-spark-csv) as well as the [StructType documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.scala) to create the schema. However all methods lead to the same custom schema, `customSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(A,IntegerType,true), StructField(B,DoubleType,true))`

`toDF` method works just fine without a custom schema. However I want to force a custom schema. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

`schema` is a property. You should use schema when you want to get `StructType` of `DataFrame` or `Dataset`.

```
val df = values.toDF
df.schema
//prints
StructType(StructField(_1,IntegerType,false), StructField(_2,DoubleType,false))
```

To convert a vector to a `DataFrame` or `Dataset`, you can use [`spark.createDataFrame`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@createDataFrame(rowRDD:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row],schema:org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) or `spark.createDataset`. These methods are overloaded and they expect `RDD` or `JavaRDD` or `java.util.List` or `Row` and schema information. You can do the following to convert your `Vector` into `DataFrame`:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(vec.toDF.rdd, customSchema)
df.schema
//prints
StructType(StructField(A,IntegerType,true), StructField(B,DoubleType,true))
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This makes total sense.