# Force Spark to read CSV values as FloatType when the numbers are represented explicitly as floats

Tags: apache-spark, schema

I have csv file with hundreds of columns. So I represented values in the file explicitly to show as floats, but Spark infers as double. This is troubling as data size is huge and casting again on all columns is to be avoided. Though I could not find any clue upon searching, I was wondering if there is a solution to this problem. I am using Spark 3.3 and the issue is demonstrated below:

```
$ cat test.csv
Word    Wt1     Wt2
hello   1.0F    2.0F
hi      2.0F    4.0F
```

In spark-shell:

```
scala> val x = 2.0F
val x: Float = 2.0

scala> val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("test.csv")
val df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Word: string, Wt1: double ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show()
+-----+---+---+
| Word|Wt1|Wt2|
+-----+---+---+
|hello|1.0|2.0|
|   hi|2.0|4.0|
+-----+---+---+

scala> df.dtypes
val res6: Array[(String, String)] = Array((Word,StringType), (Wt1,DoubleType), (Wt2,DoubleType))
```

PS: The use case of mine has strings in the first 5 columns and the rest are all floats. However, the exact number of columns is not known apriori.

PS2: Upon inclusion of the suggested solution by @leleogere that worked perfectly in `spark-shell`, overload errors were found. The reason was that the two column lists were created as `ListBuffers` that needed to be converted to `Array` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually specify the schema to the CSV reader instead of letting it inferring it by itself:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType}

val numberOfStringColumns = 1  // 5 in your case

val columnsNames = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", "true").csv("test.csv").columns
// I don't think that the above live is a problem because
// no data is actually read as we don't call any action

val (stringCols, floatCols) = columnsNames.splitAt(numberOfStringColumns)
// the above line assumes that the string columns are the first ones of the dataframe

val schema = StructType(
  stringCols.map(c => StructField(c, StringType)) ++
  floatCols.map(c => StructField(c, FloatType))
)

val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", "true").schema(schema).csv("test.csv")

df.show()
// +-----+---+---+
// | Word|Wt1|Wt2|
// +-----+---+---+
// |hello|1.0|2.0|
// |   hi|2.0|4.0|
// +-----+---+---+

df.dtypes
// Array((Word,StringType), (Wt1,FloatType), (Wt2,FloatType))
```

EDIT: this works for Scala 2.12 and Spark 3.2, see comments for a fix for Scala 2.13 and Spark 3.3

Comment: The reason for not being able to specify manually is the sheer number of columns. Hence the attempt to make the reading to `FloatType` automatic by specifying `F` in the values. Could that be done?

Comment: Not sure that it can be done with that `F`, but I might have another idea in mine, let me try it and update the answer

Comment: I could automate schema generation into a string, but am unable presently to actually use it.

Comment: What about this version? I get the column names, split into string columns and float columns, then generate appropriate schema and read the csv with the correct schema

Comment: Looks like what I was trying to get done. Will check and get back, thank you.

Comment: The code throws overload errors as covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635606/overloaded-method-error-using-spark-csv . Will try to modify and see if it works.

Comment: On 3 threads of SO, the solution was to make the input into a `Seq` (or `Array`). I made the following mod, but it gives the same error: `val schema = StructType(Array(   string_cols.map(c => StructField(c, StringType)) ++    float_cols.map(c => StructField(c, FloatType)) ))`. Similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635606/overloaded-method-error-using-spark-csv

Comment: Did you run exactly this code? Like copy-pasting? It does work for me. You don't have to specify `Seq` or `Array` as `string_cols.map(c => StructField(c, StringType)) ++    float_cols.map(c => StructField(c, FloatType))` is *already* an `Array`: both `string_cols` and `string_cols` are `Array`s, using `.map` keeps them as `Array`s, and joining them with `++` yield another `Array`.

Comment: I found the bug. Splitting into `string_cols` and `float_cols` was creating `ListBuffer`. When I converted them through `.toArray`, the code worked beautifully!

Comment: Glad you found a solution! However I don't know why it worked for me... What are your scala and spark version?

Comment: Scala 2.13 on Spark 3.3.0.

Comment: I'm using scala 2.12 with Spark 3.2.0, which probably explains the difference. I'm going to specify it in my answer.